# NDK build for c++ file giving error

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm using openCV in my c++ file for the android ndk.My Android.mk file is:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
    OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
    OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    include C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
    LOCAL_MODULE    := NDKCamera
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sfmlib.cpp
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_native_app_glue
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/BTP/NDKCamera/app/src/main/jni

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    $(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
To build it I use: 

    C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/BTP/NDKCamera APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/BTP/NDKCamera/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/BTP/NDKCamera/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/BTP/NDKCamera/app/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/lib APP_STL=gnustl_static APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

I get the following error when I try to build it.

```
    C:\Users\Simran\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e>ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: NDKCamera <= sfmlib.cpp     C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/BTP/NDKCamera/app/src/main/jni/sfmlib.cpp:16:18: error:
no matching function for call to 'cv::ORB::ORB(int)'ORB detector(1000);
C:/Users/Simran/Desktop/BTP/NDKCamera/app/src/main/jni/sfmlib.cpp:285:33: error:
 no matching function for call to 'cv::FastFeatureDetector::FastFeatureDetector(
int, bool)'
  FastFeatureDetector ffd(8, true);
```

I have no idea about C++, what am I doing wrong?